# Python: Using matplotlib how can i get my boxplot when giving return_type='both'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a boxplot, but I want to customise how it looks so I have given the boxplot method argument `return_type='both'` to get both axes and dictionary. I can't seem to then grab the boxplot out again...

Code without `return_type=True`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
            columns=['mean_coverage', 'exon'], 
            data= {
               'mean_coverage': [102, 578, 75, 180],
               'exon': [1, 1, 2, 2]
             }
           )

bp = df.boxplot(
        column='mean_coverage',
        by='exon',
        patch_artist=True,
    )

bp.figure.show()
bp.figure.savefig(
    os.path.join(
        self.output_path,
        'boxplot.png'
    )
)
```

code with `return_type=True`:

```py
bp = df.boxplot(
    column='mean_coverage',
    by='exon',
    patch_artist=True,
    return_type='both'
)

for row_key, (ax,row) in bp.iteritems():
    for box in row['boxes']:
        box.set_facecolor('pink')

bp.figure.show()
bp.figure.savefig(
    os.path.join(
        self.output_path,
        'ZRSR2.png'
    )
)
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'figure'

How do I get my box plot like example 1, out of the series.

Comment: when `return_type='both'`, it returns a tuple whose first element is the axis instance.

Comment: use `bp[0][0].figure.show()` in place of `bp.figure.show()` is those last lines. Change `bp.figure.savefig` too.

Comment: or just `ax, bp = df.boxplot(..., return_type='both')`, then you can continue to use `bp` as you have been doing